# How do I pass msg.sender to a struct as a payable address?

Tags: solidity, truffle, hardhat

Currently following a tutorial and this error keeps repeating throughout my code.

I'm trying to add `msg.sender` to a struct as a payable address but the error: `Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address to address payable requested.` repeats all through the code.

Just curious how to set `msg.sender` to the struct.

Many thanks.

```js
    struct Image {
        uint256 id;
        string hash;
        string description;
        uint256 tipAmount;
        address payable author; // < ---- Invalid implicit conversion from address to address payable requested.
    }

/////

    function uploadImage(string memory _imageHash, string memory _description) public {

        require(bytes(_imageHash).length > 0, "Must Have Hash!");

        require(bytes(_description).length > 0, "Must have description");

        require(msg.sender != address(0), "Must have author address");

        imageCount++;

        images[imageCount] = Image(
            imageCount,
            _imageHash,
            _description,
            0,
            msg.sender // < ---- Invalid implicit conversion from address to address payable requested.
        );

        emit ImageCreated(imageCount, _imageHash, _description, 0, msg.sender);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the msg.sender address this way :

```
address payable addr = address(uint160(msg.sender));
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping msg.sender in
`payable(msg.sender)`
worked for me for Solidity 0.8.2

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

struct Image {
    ...
    address payable author; // < ---- 
}
```

---

and then...

```
images[imageCount] = Image(
        imageCount,
        _imageHash,
        _description,
        0,
        payable(msg.sender) // < ---- 
     );
```